# Error message in mgcv GAM when using family = gaulss()

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to use hierarchical general additive models in mgcv using the Gaussian location-scale model family. However, this family of functions throws a cryptic error when trying to fit.

Followed the guidance on HGAMs from a recent paper (https://peerj.com/articles/6876/) along with the guidance from the notes in the lmvar package write-up (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmvar/vignettes/Intro.html).

```
library(mgcv); library(datasets)

# Using the CO2 dataset for illustration

data <- datasets::CO2

# Changing the 'Plant' factor from ordered to unordered

data$Plant <- factor(data$Plant, ordered = FALSE)

# This model fits with no errors

CO2_modG_1 <- gam(log(uptake) ~ s(log(conc), k = 5, bs = 'tp') + s(Plant, k = 12, bs = 're'), data = data, method = 'REML', family = 'gaussian')

# This model fails with error

CO2_modG_2 <- gam(log(uptake) ~ s(log(conc), k = 5, bs = 'tp') + s(Plant, k = 12, bs = 're'), data = data, method = 'REML', family = gaulss())
```

This returns the error message:

```
Error in while (sqrt(mean(dlb/(dlb + lami * dS * rm)) * mean(dlb)/mean(dlb +  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a list of two formula objects to `gam()` when fitting a Gaussian location-scale model with the `gaulss()` family.

You don't say how you want to model the scale component of the model, so here's an example which should be equivalent to the `gaussian()` family where we have a constant term for the scale and a the linear predictor you provided for the mean.

```
CO2_modG_2 <- gam(list(log(uptake) ~ s(log(conc), k = 5, bs = 'tp') + 
                         s(Plant, k = 12, bs = 're'), 
                       ~ 1), 
                  data = data, method = 'REML', family = gaulss())
```

If you want to allow each plant to have it's own variance, say, then we can add terms to the second formula:

```
CO2_modG_3 <- gam(list(log(uptake) ~ s(log(conc), k = 5, bs = 'tp') + 
                         s(Plant, k = 12, bs = 're'), 
                       ~ s(Plant, k = 12, bs = 're')), 
                  data = data, method = 'REML', family = gaulss())
```

Importantly, you have to provide a list of two formula objects to this family and the second formula should only have a tilde plus the right-hand-side of the formula specifying the linear predictor for the scale parameter.

```
list(response ~ x1 + s(x2), # location linear predictor, left & right hand sided
              ~ x1 + s(x3)  # scale linear predictor, right-hand side only
    )
```

hence, as per the first example I showed above, if you want a constant term *only* in the linear predictor for the scale you need to use R's notation for the intercept or constant term; `~ 1`

```
list(response ~ x1 + s(x2), # location linear predictor, left & right hand sided
              ~ 1           # scale linear predictor, constant
    )
```